# Need to merge two xml files using Excel vba

Tags: excel, xml, vba, xpath

I need to merge two XML files in Excel VBA. 2nd XML file should be added as a sibling of 1st XML. Also have to create a `Union` after merging the XML files. For example:

1st XML file:

```
<TupleList>
    <Member FullPath="Latest : FOLDER Day Ending 06-16-2019"/>
</TupleList>
```

2nd XML file:

```
 <TupleList>
   <Member FullPath="Latest : FOLDER Day Ending 06-17-2019"/>
 </TupleList>
```

Expected Output XML file:

```
 <Union>
  <TupleList>
    <Member FullPath="Latest : FOLDER Day Ending 06-16-2019"/>
  </TupleList>
  <TupleList>
   <Member FullPath="Latest : FOLDER Day Ending 06-17-2019"/>
  </TupleList>
 </Union>
```

I tried below code but its not working as expected

```
  Set XOuter = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
  Set XOuter1 = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
  Dim appendNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
  XOuter.Load ("C:\\blp\\1stXML.xml")
  XOuter1.Load ("C:\\blp\\2ndXML.xml")
  For Each appendNode In XOuter1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes
     XOuter.DocumentElement.appendChild appendNode
  Next
```

It provides output with Tuplelist as parent and 2 Members as Child. But I want output in above-expected format.

Comment: Valid XML has a single root element - this seems to be a problem for your expected output.

Comment: Got it. Then I can create a tag `Union` before the tuplelist. Updated the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have lots of files you could put them in a folder then use cmd to combine them into one file (assuming they don't have root nodes). Then use fileSystemObject to add the root node. I decided to work with the existing document though I thought about using .appendChild and .createElement to add the root node with an additional document variable. Think I might actually prefer that.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CombineFiles()
    Dim cmd As String, fso As Object, xmlDoc As Object, numberOfFilesInFolder As Long, folder As Object
    Const FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\XML Test"
    Const COMBINED_FILE_PATH As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\XML Test\Combined.xml"

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(FOLDER_PATH)

    numberOfFilesInFolder = folder.Files.Count
    cmd = "cmd /c cd """ & folder & """ && copy *.xml Combined.xml"

    Shell cmd, vbNormalFocus

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until folder.Files.Count = numberOfFilesInFolder + 1

    AddRootNode COMBINED_FILE_PATH, fso
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    With xmlDoc
        .validateOnParse = True
        .setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        .async = False
        If Not .Load(COMBINED_FILE_PATH) Then
            Err.Raise .parseError.ErrorCode, , .parseError.reason
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
End Sub
Public Sub AddRootNode(ByVal filepath As String, fso As Object)
    Const READING = 1
    Const WRITING = 2
    Dim file As Object, contents As String

    Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(filepath, READING)

    contents = file.ReadAll
    file.Close
    contents = "<Union>" & vbCrLf & Replace$(contents, Chr$(26), vbNullString) & vbCrLf & "</Union>"
    Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(filepath, WRITING, True)
    file.Write contents
    file.Close
End Sub
```

References:

1. https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1421842
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character
3. [Combining multiple xml documents into one large one with a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377949/combining-multiple-xml-documents-into-one-large-one-with-a-batch-file)  @Bhaskar
4. [Create xml rootNode via c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141928/create-xml-rootnode-via-c-sharp)

Comment: @YasserKhalil   try adding a short delay before.

Comment: you have any blank lines at bottom of files?  Or empty files? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/input-past-end-of-file-error-62

Comment: So two files with the different xml in each? And in the right folder?

Comment: Nope. Try stepping through with F8

Comment: So timing issue. Did you put a pause before the add root node?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now solved and I tried several times. `    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
    AddRootNode COMBINED_FILE_PATH, fso
`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
Dim inDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim resultDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim rt As Object, nd

Set rt = resultDoc.appendChild(resultDoc.createElement("Union"))

Debug.Print resultDoc.XML

''using loadXML here for convenience...
inDoc.LoadXML ("<TupleList><Member FullPath=""Latest : FOLDER Day Ending 06-16-2019""/></TupleList>")
Set nd = resultDoc.importNode(inDoc.DocumentElement, True)
rt.appendChild nd

inDoc.LoadXML ("<TupleList><Member FullPath=""Latest : FOLDER Day Ending 06-17-2019""/></TupleList>")
Set nd = resultDoc.importNode(inDoc.DocumentElement, True)
rt.appendChild nd

Debug.Print resultDoc.XML
```